# How to run Joomla 1.5 on PHP5.4?

Tags: joomla1.5

I've got several J1.5 sites that need to run on PHP5.4 very, very soon.  (yes, i know - upgrade to J2.5), but the amount of customization makes it impossible to do that given the time frames I have.

I realized that we'll need to test the site top to bottom after the upgrade, but the number of PHP errors seems never ending straight out of the gate. Without suppressing all errors, it could take months just to get them to run, lol.

Does anyone know of any "general" php settings, or "global" Joomla changes that should/could be made to make this endeavour at least a little bearable?

In the spirit of stackoverflow, I should mention that I've tried various error_reporting variations, but have found that suppressing errors will get it "running", but nothing "works".

Comment: for start, upgrade to latest in 1.5 series, as Joomla got php 5.3+ compatible only from 1.5.16 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no problem running Joomla versions as low as 1.5.15 with PHP 5.4 and MySQL 5 (no fancy add-ons installed though). Maybe the errors you are reporting are mostly caused by add-ons? Did you try deactivating modules/ plug-ins?

No configuration changes were necessary on several legacy projects running Joomla 1.5. I had to manage/ migrate so far. I just switched to PHP 5.4 as global php version (provider 1&1).

If you should run into problems as long as PHP 4 and 5 run in parallel you might want to add this to your htaccess to make sure PHP 5 is being used:

```
# for PHP 5.2
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

Or specifically for PHP 5.4:

```
# for PHP 5.4
AddType x-mapp-php6 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
```

**Word of warning:** Joomla 1.5 is *really* outdated. Google Webmasterplan is giving site owners warnings if it detects sites still operating on version 1.5. There are/were video tutorials on Youtube showing how to hack into it. So better update asap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something has changed since this answer was first accepted but according to Joomla.org , joomla1.5 isn't compatible with php5.4

Source:  [http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_won't_work_on_PHP_5.4](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_won%27t_work_on_PHP_5.4)

this page is dated Apr 29, 2013